# How to get a tone like this using vox mini 5 rhythym amplifier

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

How to get a tone like this using vox mini 5 rhythym amplifier

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Vox Mini 5, but I use a tube screamer into my Vox Cambridge Reverb and accomplish sustain like that.

Answer (score 1):

A Compressor/Sustainer will do the job of the sustained notes, and then any distortion unit will give the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specs of the Vox Mini 5, and following up on PeteCon's answer it looks like you'd have to try use one of the higher gain amp models (US80's, UK90's, Cali Metal or  or US High Gain) to get the gain to go along with the on-board compression effect for the sustain.  Maybe there is a combination of these that gets you in the ballpark without needing a separate pedal.